# mysql query not working because of the version

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion, triggers, version

Lets assume the code below is inside a procedure or trigger. With the code below , i am able to convert the string "name" into characters and then convert each character to ascii code , merge it all together and store in the variable "result"

For example: lets say name is "hello" then it will look like this "104101108108111" where h = 104, e = 101, l = 108, o = 111.

As i searched CTE's only work with 8.0 + , so i was wondering if someone can help me doing what i need to do so it can work on the older version as well maybe without using CTE's or something. Thank you

```
    declare name varchar(15);
    declare result decimal(64,0);

    with recursive cte as (
        select name as name, left(name, 1) as val, 1 as idx
        union all
        select name, substring(name, idx + 1, 1), idx + 1 
        from cte 
        where idx < char_length(name)
    )
    select group_concat(ascii(val) order by idx separator '') ascii_word from cte into result;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table of numbers, you can do this using `join`:

```
select group_concat(ascii(substr(name, n.n, 1)) order by n.n eparator '') as ascii_word
       into result
from name join
     (select 1 as n union all
      select 2 union all
      . . .
     ) n
     on length(name) <= n.n;
```

You can either expand the list to some reasonable length for your problem or maintain a numbers table with more than enough rows in the database.  You could also using an existing table, with code like this:

```
 (select (@rn := @rn + 1) as n
  from existing cross join
       (select @rn := 0) params
  where @rn < length(name)
 )
```